# Why I have to decrease cnt in putc function? I have one more character. Is it not logical to increase it?

Tags: c, macros

In 'C Programming Language', the authors added this piece of code:

```
#define putc(c, p) (--(p->cnt) >= 0) ? \
            (*p->ptr++ = c) : _flushbuf(c, p)
```

But I can't understand why I have to decrease cnt. Is it not logical to increase it (because we have one more character)?

Answer (score 0):

After `p->ptr++`, `p->ptr` moves forward for one step, so accordingly `p->cnt` decreases. If `p->cnt` is not maintained, `p->ptr` will be filled with characters, then overflow.

Comment: I got it. Then, when ptr is at the end of the buffer, flushbuf() puts all buffer data (changed) back to the file?

Comment: @AbdulAxundzade I haven't read the book, but I guess it should do. And what's more it would reset `p->ptr` and `p->cnt`.

Answer (score 0):

The `_cnt` member is meant to count the "number of characters left" in the buffer, according to the comment in the definition of `struct _iobuf` on the previous page.  For an output stream, this means the number of bytes of space remaining in the buffer.  So when you add another character to the buffer, there is one less character of available space.

For `getc`, which makes sense for input streams, `_cnt` instead counts the number of characters of *data* left in the buffer.

This implementation wouldn't work if you tried to mix `getc` and `putc` calls on the same stream with a nonempty buffer.  However, C requires that you call `fflush` in between reading and writing, which would avoid the issue.

Comment: Then, why we do the same operation in getc? These functions are opposite